# How does PIL Image save NumPy arrays with non-integer and non-positive values?

Tags: python, image, numpy, python-imaging-library

I have a NumPy array of size 28 x 280, which contains real number values (both positive and negative values). I am using the following code to save this array to file through a PIL Image -

```
img = Image.fromarray(img)
img.save(save_path, "PNG")
```

Now, when I load this saved image using PIL using the following code -

```
img = Image.open(save_path)
img = np.array(img)
print(img[:,:,0]) # since the image is saved in RGB by default, and the channels are simply all the same, I am printing out only one of the channels
print(img.shape) # printing shape of loaded image for sanity check
```

The above gives me the following output -

```
array([[ 0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0],
       [14, 14, 14],
       [ 0,  0,  0],
       [14, 14, 14],
       [ 0,  0,  0],
       [ 2,  2,  2],
       [10, 10, 10],
       [ 0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0],
       [ 6,  6,  6],
       [ 0,  0,  0],
       [19, 19, 19],
       [16, 16, 16],
       [ 0,  0,  0],
       [ 9,  9,  9],
       [14, 14, 14],
       [ 5,  5,  5],
-- omitting the remaining matrix for spatial reasons
```

The original matrix looks something like the following if that helps -

```
   1.54009545e+00  1.14122391e-01 -5.44282794e-01 -1.66106954e-01]
 [-2.70073628e+00 -6.25280142e+00  1.77814519e+00 -8.72797012e+00
   9.91206944e-01  6.63580036e+00  6.84081888e+00 -1.18705761e+00
  -4.54479456e+00 -5.26672935e+00  4.91975927e+00 -5.48409176e+00
  -3.93164325e+00  5.19110155e+00  1.26516495e+01  9.93665600e+00
  -5.70824432e+00  5.72582603e-01 -4.31831169e+00 -9.31297874e+00
   2.13714447e-02 -9.82507896e+00 -2.47176766e+00 -1.94778728e+00
  -1.85507727e+00 -8.01630592e+00 -4.42644596e+00  5.74180269e+00]
 [ 3.32923412e+00  1.50732050e+01 -1.01800518e+01  1.85193479e-01
  -1.77801073e+00 -4.91134501e+00 -4.94232035e+00  5.52533197e+00
  -3.84771490e+00 -5.61370182e+00 -2.91945863e+00 -9.53506768e-01
   7.03971624e-01  1.26758552e+00 -1.29794350e+01 -1.08105397e+00
  -5.57984650e-01 -1.50801647e+00 -3.45247960e+00 -6.14299655e-01
  -4.83907032e+00  5.44770575e+00  2.50088573e+00 -2.45785332e+00
  -3.94766003e-01  7.80810177e-01 -1.66951954e+00 -5.23118067e+00]
 [ 1.24226892e+00 -4.30912447e+00  1.14384556e+00 -5.38896322e+00
  -5.95073175e+00  5.03882837e+00  4.15563917e+00 -7.99412632e+00
  -1.68129158e+00 -2.23124218e+00  2.24080634e+00 -5.57195246e-01
  -2.29391623e+00 -2.70431495e+00  9.87635612e+00 -2.90223390e-01
   3.25407982e+00  3.67051101e+00 -2.86848998e+00 -4.53229618e+00
  -3.80941963e+00  3.66697168e+00  3.98574305e+00 -1.50027335e-01
  -8.77485275e+00  2.20300531e+00  4.97666216e+00  2.27730870e+00]]

-- again, omitting large chunks for spatial reasons
```

Question -

1. Here, from what I understand, PIL is implicitly converting the reals to `uint8` format (0 to 255 pixel values), but I want to know how exactly conversion of reals to `uint8` takes place? Are the real pixel values rounded off or truncated to the closest integer, if so, what happens to the negative pixel values?
2. Also, when I try to visualize the PIL image by simply opening it, it just shows me a black screen, like so -
   [image]

But, the weird thing is that, when I multiply the np array by 255, like so - `img = img * 255`, and then save it, it shows some values, like so -

[image]

Is it just that the pixel values initially are too light to be perceived by my eyes? I think so, but I just want to confirm.

Comment: [From the documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html#png) when using the `save` method from `PIL`, the writer for `PNG` format uses 8 bits (0-255) if the option `bits` is ignored, i.e. it uses 8-bits for saving the image by default.

Comment: Thanks. I think I was not very clear. If my matrix pixel value range is only between say for example 0 to 20, it seems like PIL is not trying to scale these values to 0 to 255, so that needs to be done manually if I am right?

Comment: @Megh Yes, that is right. It looks like negative values are set to 0, and positive values are truncated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to save negative and floating point data as an image, you should probably use **TIFF** format.

**PNG** is only able to store unsigned integer data at up to 16-bit/channel, i.e. in range 0..65535.

---

Here is a demonstration of saving positive and negative floating point numbers in a TIFF and then retrieving them:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Set height and width
h, w = 5, 4

# Create image from Numpy array of float32 and save as TIFF
naA = np.linspace(-1000, 1000, h*w, dtype=np.float32).reshape((h,w))
Image.fromarray(naA).save('floats.tif')

# Read back image and compare
imB = Image.open('floats.tif')
naB = np.array(imB)
```

Now print both and check same:

```
In [101]: naA
Out[101]: 
array([[-1000.     ,  -894.7368 ,  -789.4737 ,  -684.2105 ],
       [ -578.9474 ,  -473.6842 ,  -368.42105,  -263.1579 ],
       [ -157.89473,   -52.63158,    52.63158,   157.89473],
       [  263.1579 ,   368.42105,   473.6842 ,   578.9474 ],
       [  684.2105 ,   789.4737 ,   894.7368 ,  1000.     ]],
      dtype=float32)

In [102]: naB
Out[102]: 
array([[-1000.     ,  -894.7368 ,  -789.4737 ,  -684.2105 ],
       [ -578.9474 ,  -473.6842 ,  -368.42105,  -263.1579 ],
       [ -157.89473,   -52.63158,    52.63158,   157.89473],
       [  263.1579 ,   368.42105,   473.6842 ,   578.9474 ],
       [  684.2105 ,   789.4737 ,   894.7368 ,  1000.     ]],
      dtype=float32)
```